# Изменение цвета текста на кнопке

Tags: android

Есть `xml`-файлик, в котором меняю цвет кнопки, в зависимости от её состояния:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Всё работает отлично, но еще нужно менять цвет текста кнопок
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте написать такой же selector, положить его в res/color и задать его в качестве параметра:

```
android:textColor="@color/selector"
```